# How to get the id of the controls created inside the iterator?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
for (Iterator i = mysched.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

        Properties p = (Properties) i.next();

        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        label = new TextView(this);
        label.setText(p.getStartTime() +"-"+p.getEndTime()+"\nDay: "+p.getDay());

        label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        label.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9598AB"));
        label.setPadding(10,50,30,35);//left,top,right,down
        label.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(label,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        TextView stats = new TextView(this);
        stats.setText(p.getCourseId()+" "+p.getSection()+" "+p.getRoom());
        stats.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        stats.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9598AB"));
        stats.setPadding(40,60,0,58);//left,top,right,down
        stats.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(stats,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

         // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```

Here is my label created using iterator that i am creating dynamically so that each data will have label for each. How to get the id of each label created? I want to pass the id of the label to another class and also the item inside.

Comment: did you try `label.getId()`?

Comment: i tried a counter sir :)

Comment: By ID, you mean the Android view's id, or your custom ID?

Comment: Keep references to *all* the labels you're creating so you can get at them later; the variable `label` should be an array of labels or a list of labels, not a single label.